# How to skip EF Take when input parameter is null?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have EF query with `.Take()` method. How many records to take I get from input parameter. But in case this parameter is `NULL` I don't want to call `Take` at all. Currently, if param is `NULL` I set it to `int.MaxValue`. Should I divide my code on `IQueryable<>` blocks and check this parameter or there exists "oneline" solution?

```
var itemsPerPage = int.MaxValue;
      
if (input.ItemsPerPage.HasValue &&  input.ItemsPerPage.Value > 0)
{
    itemsPerPage = input.ItemsPerPage.Value;
}

var result = await query.Take(itemsPerPage).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: `query.Take(input.ItemsPerPage ?? int.MaxValue)` would be the oneliner solution but I don't think it is efficient. Or you can try something like this `var result = await (input.ItemsPerPage == null ? query : qurey.Take(itemsPerPage))ToListAsync();`

Comment: `var bob = query; if (condition) bob = bob.Take(itemsPerPage);`

Answer (score 2):

The standard method is to do `if` check and change the query itself if necessary.

```
IQueryable<SomeEntity> query = ...

if (input.ItemsPerPage.GetValueOrDefault() > 0)
{
    query = query.Take(input.ItemsPerPage.Value);
}

// other if operators here

var result = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd remove the `.Take()` call entirely if `ItemsPerPage` is null.

```
ResultType result;
if (input.ItemsPerPage.HasValue &&  input.ItemsPerPage.Value > 0)
{
  result = await query.Take(input.ItemsPerPage.Value).ToListAsync();
}
else
{
  result = await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

If you're that way inclined, you could "one-line" this:

```
var result = input.ItemsPerPage.HasValue &&  input.ItemsPerPage.Value > 0
  ? await query.Take(input.ItemsPerPage.Value).ToListAsync()
  : await query.ToListAsync();
```